# Элементы язычества в фольклоре

Tags: литература, фольклор

Анимизм и его проявление в фольклоре

Answer (score 3):

Почти все сказки о животных имеют анимистическую природу. Например, в первоначальном варианте сказки "Маша и медведи" медведи убивали девочку, посмевшую потревожить священное животное, но затем с десакрализацией животных итог сказки стал менее печальным.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь, может быть, поможет:
http://nsportal.ru/ap/library/drugoe/2012/12/05/folklor-i-sistema-pervobytnykh-verovaniy-otrazhenie-v-literature
http://superinf.ru/view_helpstud.php?id=2847